# How to send ether using a wallet contract from the Parity Wallet?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

How do you send ETH from a wallet contract using the [Parity Wallet](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Parity-Wallet)?

I tried selecting the wallet contract, and selected execute contract but I didn't see an option to send ETH to another address.

Comment: It might be helpful to post screenshots and addresses of the wallet contracts and steps you tried? Or screenshots of the equivalent transaction in Mist. It might be the case that you used a contract that doesn't have the function you want, or the function might have a name that you didn't expect.

Answer (score 2):

The Parity team has taken the time to write [incredible documentation](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki) about their wallet. You will not only find the answer to your problem, but to many future ones you may have. Take a look at the docs for your solution.

For your specific question, follow the logical steps in the GUI. Specifically:

1) Open the GUI

2) Click on the "Accounts Management" tab

3) Click "Transfer". You will see this screen:

[image]

4) Enter the recipient's address, the amount you want to send, and then press send. Type in password.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer is not in the documentation.

Comment: I provided an example. Please see that and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Well, thank you but that example is helpful for transfering from accounts. My problem is transfering from a wallet contract.

Comment: Also, unfortunately my question was quite clear until people chose to edit my question and changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: @MistProblemsGuy "Wallet contract" is still in the question, but I've added it back to the title and first sentence if that improves it. As you posted the question, you can always edit it. Anyone who wants to answer can also edit the question to make it clearer (I thought the double use of "wallet" in the title is redundant).  I think an answer covering both ways of transferring is more helpful, than 2 separate questions (so maybe we want to put back the title to "How to send ether from the Parity Wallet?")

Comment: I understand where you're coming from and sorry if I came off as rude. Most importantly, I appreciate you trying to help as I'm still learning to use SE. In addition, I'm surprised nobody can answer this question. Unless Parity doesnt yet support this feature, it should be pretty straightforward, no?